# Is there a way to define onClick element within <a> tag that will not launch href?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, href

I have a list of box elements that are clickable using `<a href>` and in this box element I want to add icon that will do something `onClick`, but will not fire `<a href>`. To be more precize I am using React for that. I pass down a function in props to child component that is covered with `a` tag. When I click specific icon I just want to launch the function I passed and not go to `href`. If You click anywhere else within box it will fire `href`.

I tried adding `<a>` element on the icon and override original `<a>`, but it didn't really work out and it is not allowed by HTML. Right now both `a` and `onClick` fires up together.

Here is some code I reduced it to simple example instead of passing the whole thing:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
  <div className="content is-relative">
    <p className="stream__title">{this.props.stream.title}</p>
    <p className="stream__game">{this.props.stream.game}</p>
    <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => this.props.follow(this.props.stream.user)}
            className="stream__follow" icon="heart" size="lg"/>
  </div>
</a>
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: event.preventDefault(); this will help inside the click listener

Comment: Wow thank You. That was so simple and I missed that

Comment: Why you do not set it as **href="#"** or **href="javascript:void(0)"**
iyour <a> tag will not redirect you.
And why you set it to some link?

Comment: As I stated in the question. I want the rest of element inside `a` tag to redirect, but only this icon to do something else. Disabling `a` altogether is not an option.

Comment: a href="#", this would not redirect to any other url

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because icon is wrapped inside box.
In javascript events are bubbled up by default.

i.e. An event of clicking on icon will be bubbled up and will be handled by box href.

If you want to change this behaviour, use `stopPropogation()`.

```
<div onclick="alert(`I will not handle it anymore`)">
  <button onclick="event.stopPropagation()">Let me do it for once!</button>
</div>
```